# Why is my if statement not executing and showing the Toast?

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple password application now.

Something like I did in VB.

I have my code

```
package com.example.password;
import android.widget.*;

import com.example.password.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn1;
    EditText et1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if ("u" == et1.getText().toString()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yay!! GOOD GUESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        }

    }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; his adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

No compilation or runtime errors, but I get no `Toast` popup when I get the "password" right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if ("u" == et1.getText().toString())
```

to

```
if ("u".equals(et1.getText().toString()))
```

You can also do

```
if (et1.getText().toString().equals("u"))
```

but I believe the first way is safer against `NPE` but if you check for `null` then it doesn't really matter. The way you are currently doing it checks that they reference the same object. Using `.equals("string")` checks that the values are equal, when dealing with `String`

**[Java String function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)**

Comment: THANKS A BUNCH! so should I always use this method?

Comment: When checking for equality of value for `String`s, yes!. As I put in my edit, your way checks to see if they are the same object but not necessarily the same value. You are welcome a BUNCH! :)

Comment: props for your first way to avoid the NPE. I would say stick with that

Comment: @ElefantPhace thanks! Although, I don't use it as much (shhhh!) because it doesn't feel natural to me so I make sure to check for `null`s when I need to but I probably should use it more since I know its better. :O

Comment: @user2130068 if this works for what you need, you may kindly accept the answer so others with the same issue can find the answer easier